# how to set html node value using webview with javafx

Tags: java, javafx, webview

i am trying to set the value of the html form elements after loaded into webview.I tried to set using

```
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
HTMLFormElement form = (HTMLFormElement) doc.getElementsByTagName("form").item(0);
NodeList nodes = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
nodes.item(1).setNodeValue("yadayada"); //this is where i am setting the value
```

but no success. can anybody help me out. here is my code.

```
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();                 
if (doc!=null && doc.getElementsByTagName("form").getLength() > 0) {
      HTMLFormElement form = (HTMLFormElement) doc.getElementsByTagName("form").item(0);
      String username = null;
      String password = null;
      NodeList nodes = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
      if(nodes.item(i).hasAttributes()){
          NamedNodeMap attr = nodes.item(i).getAttributes();
          for (int j=0 ; j<attr.getLength();j++){
             Attr atribute = (Attr)attr.item(j);
             if(atribute.getValue().equals("password")){
             System.out.println("Password detected");
             nodes.item(i).setNodeValue("123456");
           }
         }
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post a sample HTML file this is supposed to work with? (Better still, create a [MCVE].)

Comment: thanks @James_D for your help. I got my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution after surfing the web. The problem was i was using set node value but values of input tags are set using HTMLInputElement.This link was valuabe for me
[Performing an automated form post of login using webview](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/6722397)
for example

```
HTMLInputElement password = (HTMLInputElement) nodes.item(0).setValue("yadayada");
```